# как прикрепить несколько файлов к письму через php mailer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer

Я получаю данные через ajax запрос вот код

```
const formData = new FormData(bigForm);
if (filesArr.lenth > 0){
  for (let i = 0; i < filesArr.length; i++){
    formData.append('file_'+i, filesArr[i]);
  }
}
if (error === 0){
  bigForm.classList.add('_sending')
  console.log(formData.get('option'));
  let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  });
```

Как мне переделать этот кусок кода чтобы прикреплялось несколько файлов к письму?

```
if (!empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){
    $body .= "<p>Файлы:</p>";

    $filePath = __DIR__ . "/files/" . $_FILES['files']['name'];
    if (copy($_FILES['files']['tmp__name'], $filePath)){
        $fileAttach = $filePath;
        $mail->addAttachment($fileAttach);
    }
}
```

Я плохо разбираюсь в php поэтому в аналогичных вопросах не смог понять код.

Answer (score 0):

Код можжно модифицировать так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
    if (!empty($_FILES['files_' . $i]['tmp_name'])){
        $body .= "<p>Файлы:</p>";

        $filePath = __DIR__ . "/files/" . $_FILES['files_' . $i]['name'];
        if (copy($_FILES['files_' . $i]['tmp__name'], $filePath)){
            $fileAttach = $filePath;
            $mail->addAttachment($fileAttach);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а у меня файлы должны быть не с разными именами? я же в js делал название ‘file_’+i , а не просто files